# The procedure of Opening a website using IE8

Tags: c++, c, sdk

I want to know when I'm using IE8 open a website (like www.yahoo.com), which API will be called by IE8? so I can hook these API to capture which website that IE8 opening currently.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a URL into the browser, the browser (usually) makes an HTTP request to the server identified by the URL. To make the request, the IP address of the server is required, which is obtained by a DNS lookup of the host (domain) name.

Once the response -- usually containing HTML markup -- is received, the browser renders it to display the webpage.

More details available here: [what happens when you type in a URL in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092527/what-happens-when-you-type-in-a-url-in-browser)

So, in the general case, no "API" request as such is made. (Technically speaking, you can think of the original HTTP request to the server as an API request). The sort of "API" request you presumably mean, however, is not made in this general case just described. Those requests happens when the JavaScript executing on the page makes an **Ajax** HTTP request (XmlHttpRequest) to the web server to carry out some operation.

I am not sure about IE8, but the "developer tools" feature of most modern browsers (including IE9 and IE10), would let you see the Ajax HTTP requests that the webpage made as it carried out different operations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but if you want to send a request to remote server, you have to call the API(maybe like socket send API) to complete this request, right.

Comment: Yes. The browser would use the Socket API provided by the operating system to do that. If you are using IE/Windows, this would be the Winsock API. You could google that for more details.

Answer (score 0):

IE uses Microsoft's [WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library API to interact with web servers.

You may want to look for a network monitoring/sniffing API, which you could use to examine HTTP requests, and determine the URLs the browser is using.