# How exacty HTTP protocol works?

Tags: sockets, http, http-headers

Sir i want to know how http works.When you type "www.youtube.com" in browser, following steps occurs.

```
    - DNS look-up for "www.youtube.com" (suppose you get 1.1.1.1)
    - Open socket to 1.1.1.1 port=80 and send a GET HTTP packet on it.
    - Receive a response on that socket.
```

Am i right or there are any other steps?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2092602/987896) has nice explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it's that simple though not dead-on in syntax.

1. Resolve domain if not an IP (DNS query)
2. Open port 80 by default if not SSL and not overridden by a colon (http: //host:port/)
3. Send request (#1) for http: //host/uri/here?other=stuff&too
4. Receive response (#2)

Example request: (#1) uses and must be ended by two Carriage Return and Line Feeds (CrLf)

```
GET /uri/here?other=stuff&too HTTP/1.1 
Host: host
Other: Headers, too.  Such as cookies
Header: Value
```

Example response: (#2)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Other: Headers, too.  Such as cookies
Header: Value

<html>Actual HTTP payload is here, could be HTML data, downloaded file data, etc.
```