# What is end-to-end series of events happens when you hit URL and get response

Tags: url, dns, httprequest

Can someone please explain what is the series of events occurs when you hit a URL in browser.

E.g. I hit google.com or yahoo.com from browser to reaching server and coming back the response what are the role players in between like DNS, router, server protocal, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092527/what-happens-when-you-type-in-a-url-in-browser

Comment: See this post at superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/31468/what-exactly-happens-when-you-browse-a-website-in-your-browser it explains it very well.