# How to avoid the flicker of Angular 2 to a new page of the url?

Tags: angular, typescript, router, smartadmin

When I enter my page: **http://localhost/dashboard** by typing it in the url, and then entering another page **http://localhost/owners**, also typing it in the url, produces a blink.

How can I avoid it, similar to the example on this page?

https://smartadmin-ng2.github.io/#/dashboard/analytics

Or what points should I check?

Comment: when u put a new url manually, the whole application is reinstantiated and becuase of that u see a delay.

Comment: How so, @JuliaPassynkova? What does the browser do differently when I press "Enter"  in the browser's address bar versus clicking on an href link on the page?

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092527/what-happens-when-you-type-in-a-url-in-browser

Comment: Huge difference. Clicking on href inside SPA (single page app) - the application does not reload, so no flick.

Comment: @wannadream, that explains what happens when you press "Enter" in the browser's address bar, but it doesn't explain how (or if) that behaviour differs from a simple href link that issues a GET request on an address.

Comment: anything after #/...... is intercepted and handled by Angular framework. Within the application, relative herf link are all managed. If you type something in URL, that is out of control of Angular. It's a browser behavior.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I think I understand what you mean. In the SPA in OP's example they href isn't issuing a plain old GET request on a document, it's an AJAX call, right?

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense

Comment: in SPA routing does the job - remove old components and add new ones. in Angular we use Angular route but all other SPA frameworks have similar software. Btw, it might be a case when there is no ajax call between route changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a new url manually, the whole application is re-instantiated and because of that you see a delay.

Clicking on href inside SPA (single page app) - the application does not reload, so no flick.   In SPA routing does the job when href is changed - it removes old components and add new ones. In Angular we use Angular Router but all other SPA frameworks have similar routing software. Btw, it might be a case when there is no ajax call between route changes

Comment: That is to say, that internally there would be some script that to avoid the refreshment when it changes the url?